# How do I change the 'New File' destination in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, user-interface

Everytime I click 'New File' in Xcode, it opens a Finder window with the project folder. I want to change the default 'New File' destination to some arbitrary folder.

How can I do this?

Edit: When I say 'New File', I am referring to **File** > **New** > **File**

Comment: 'New File' or 'Add files to ...'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You will always have to navigate to the parent folder you want the new file to appear in.

You can, however, ensure the new file gets added to the correct *Group* within Xcode by selecting the *Group* (left click) and then selecting *New File...* from the context menu (right click).

I think this is a missing usability feature as Xcode should map *Groups* to filesystem *Folders* where ever possible.

[image]